# Bootstrap js plugin source code how $('body').on('focus.typeahead.data-api', '[data-provide="typeahead"]', function (e) works out?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking at the js plugin of bootstrap,namely bootstrap-typeahead.js.I can't figure out **how** element is selected.

```
$('body').on('focus.typeahead.data-api', '[data-provide="typeahead"]', function (e)
```

I know element is actually selected by the data-provide part,but when I look through jquery.js , I can't figure out how it is done.From .on() part I went to event.add() part then I became more confused.Can anyone tell me **how that's done**?

I know **what** it does,but want to know **how**.How element is selected?
I need more ideas here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of the `on()` method is the event, in this case it is namespaced - the event is `focus` in the `typeahead.data-api` namespace

The second argument is a filter-selector for event-delegation purposes. The actual event handler is attached to the `body` element, but the handler function is only executed for events coming from elements with the `data-provide` attribute with a value of `typeahead`

Comment: Thanks for reply.I understand the main idea.But I can't see how element is actually selected by the data-provide attribute.I have problem reading the jquery source code.I went to $.event.add: function( elem, types, handler, data, selector ),then got lost here.I need some more explanation.

Comment: Maybe that's where you're going wrong - the element isn't selected with the `data-provide` attribute. The selected element in this example is `body`. Any event under the specified namespace that reaches the `body` element is checked to see if it has a `data-provide` attribute, and if it does if its value is `typeahead`. If so, the handler is executed. Try looking at the source code for `on`...

Comment: Actually on calls event.add that's why i went there.I will look at the source again.Thanks again!

Comment: but looking at the source for on will tell you what the arguments accept

Comment: The event is the focus event, it's just namespaced. You're right, there is nothing in the source code that triggers the event. But the OP did not ask how the event was triggered, he asked how the element was selected.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov as danwellman said, it's not a custom event, it's just a normal `focus` event.  This will bubble up to the body when *any* element under the body is focused.  The `focus` event in this case is [namespaced](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) to allow for better event handling.  An example of this, from the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#overview) allows one to unbind from all bootstrap events using `$('body').off('.data-api')`, or just unbind the typeahead event using `$('body').off('.typeahead.data-api')`

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching the answer to the **why** (As I did. Why would somebody register such an awkward focus event handler.), the reason is pure html based initialization of the typeahead control, as it is described in the [documentation HERE:](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead)

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
```

Nodes with the `data-provide="typeahead"` attribute  are activated as typeaheads as the document receives focus...